# How to get value of useState variable in function that passed to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The best way to describe question is my code:

```
function EstateParamsList({ estateType, category }) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
  const [params, setParams] = useState({})
  const [showPopUp, setShowPopUp] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (category && typeof category.id !== undefined) {
      return db.collection(`dictionaries/ESTATE_PARAMS/${estateType}/${category.id}/params`).onSnapshot(response => {
        const paramsObject = {}
        response.forEach(param => {
          paramsObject[param.id] = {
            ...convertParamObjetcToFieldsConfig(param.data()),
            change: fieldChangedHandler
          }
        })
        setParams(paramsObject)
        setIsLoading(false)
      })
    } else {
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
  }, [category])
 console.log(params)
  const fieldChangedHandler = (event, fieldIdentifier) => {
    if(params)
      console.log(params)
  }
```

So i have **params** variable, that im init with object, that i'm getting async from firebase. Implementation of initializing you can see in **useEffect method**. For every object i want to pass ref for the function "fieldChangedHandler", for managing value of inputs.

**fieldChangedHandler** is a method of my **EstateParamsList**. But there i cant get value of **params!**

Question is WHY? I'm calling fieldChangedHandler only after everything was rendered, and async request was done.

Below is console log of params. Why in func is empty **params**?

[image]

Calling:

```
const renderParamsAsFields = params => {
  const fields = []
  for (const key in params) {
    fields.push(<Field {...params[key]} changed={event => params[key].change(event, key)} />)
  }
  return fields.length ? fields : <div className='EstateParamsManager-EmptyValues'>Нет параметров</div>
}
```

Comment: How exactly are you calling fieldChangeHandler?

Comment: Did you not see `React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'estateType' and 'fieldChangedHandler'`?

Comment: That's not reasone of my problem!. fieldChangedHandler is not dependence! You want to tell that i need to make query ALWAYS when user making input in the field?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo i have update my post. With code of call. Please re-read everything) I have made some changes

Comment: Why would you create a paramsObject as object and then later create an array out if it again. You could just [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the response to an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use curried function?

```
const createFieldChangedHandler = (
  params,
  fieldIdentifier
) => event => {
  if (params) console.log(params);
};

function EstateParamsList({ estateType, category }) {
//... other code
  useEffect(() => {
    //...other code
    change: createFieldChangedHandler(
       paramsObject,
       param.id
    ),
    //...other code
   }, [category, estateType]);//fixed missing dependency
```

When you call the change function you should already have the right values in scope:

```
<Field {...params[key]} changed={params[key].change} />
```

Comment: Also thought about tat. This is the solution. i have checked. its working. But i cant figure out why my example is not working. Maybe i'ts making some kind of closure when i'm passing my func, and coping body of func instead of ref, that's why im getting empty object of params cause it's initialized by empty object

Comment: @WhoIsDT at the time you set `change: fieldChangedHandler` params is `{}` when you setParams then you create a new value for params but fieldChangehandler has `{}` in closure. With the other option you put `paramsObject` in closure scope and then **mutate** that.

Comment: that's it! So thank you HMR! everything clear:) Have a nice day:)